# How to register using subdomain field in django?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I want to register company details using subdomain so that the user can login using subdomain.

I created models.forms and views but i am facing problem with rendering the form

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    sub_domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_limit = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'address',
                  'sub_domain', 'country']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request_user = kwargs.pop('request_user', None)
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class RegistrationView(AdminRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "company_register.html"

    def is_valid(self, form):
        company = Company.objects.create_company(form.cleaned_data['name'],
                                        form.cleaned_data['address'],
                                        form.cleaned_data['sub_domain'],
                                        form.cleaned_data['country'])
        company.save()
        return super(RegistrationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls

```
path('register/', RegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

company_register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Registration</h1>
<form method="POST" class="user-form">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Where i have done mistake as i am a newbie can someone help me?Thanks

Comment: What's the error/issue?

Answer (score 0):

Template name is different from the template file name you paste

```
    template_name = "company_register.html"
```

It should be

```
    template_name = "reg.html"
```

Also, the following should usually be enough, unless you want to do some custom validation in your view.

```
class RegistrationView(AdminRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "company_register.html"
```

Comment: That is not a problem .....I wrote like that its actually company_register.html only i kept